# Customized Google Maps with CSS + Javascript / Company Directory Links

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directory

I am trying to set up a custom Google Map that will have a directory of businesses down the side.

Please see my example link at the end of this post.

You can currently click on the green icons and open the custom popups but I need to create company links off of the map in the sidebar that when clicked will open up the appropriate pop up on the map.

Please let me know what I need that would allow it to open each of the company popups when clicking links in the sidebar beside the map.

Here is the example, minus the links on the sidebar that i'm asking about:
http://digitour360.com/test-map/

Here is the Javascript used in my example, if this helps determine how to call up the popups:

```
<!-- your api key is used here -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stylizedmap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function () {
var a = [
"http://2.s3.envato.com/files/29891006/mountains%206.jpg",
"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/29962392/mountains%2014.jpg",
"http://2.s3.envato.com/files/29035356/oetztal_8800.jpg",
"http://1.s3.envato.com/files/22469879/IMG_3536.jpg",
"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/22441185/IMG_6149_2.jpg"
];
var b = [
"http://1.s3.envato.com/files/28915052/Garden.JPG"
];

var sparkles = [
"images/sparkles1.jpg"
];

var accent = [
"images/accent.jpg"
];  

 var dougherty = [
"images/dougherty.jpg"
];

var centurion = [
"images/centurion.jpg"
]; 

var gardner = [
"images/gardner.jpg"
];

$("#map").StylizedMap({
zoomLevel: 17,
styles: $().StylizedMap.styles.gray,
center: {   
lat: 35.884773,
long: -78.745691
},
locations: [{   
lat: 35.884752,
long: -78.74959,
title: 'Accent Imaging, Inc.<br/><a href="http://www.accentimaging.com" target="_blank">www.accentimaging.com&nbsp;&rarr;</a>',
sub_title: "8121 Brownleigh Drive, Raleigh, NC 27617",
slides: accent,
active: true
}, {
lat: 35.885556,
long: -78.749399,
title: 'Sparkles Restoration<br/><a href="http://www.sparkkles.com" target="_blank">www.sparkkles.com&nbsp;&rarr;</a>',
sub_title: "738 Lincoln Road Miami Beach, FL 33139",    
slides: sparkles
}, {
lat: 35.882468,
long: -78.748927,
title: 'Centurion Construction<br/><a href="http://www.centurionconstruction.com" target="_blank">www.centurionconstruction.com&nbsp;&rarr;</a>',
sub_title: "3301 Glen Royal Rd, Raleigh, NC 27617",
slides: centurion
}, {
lat: 35.886834,
long: -78.749587,
title: 'Gardner-Marsh Gas Equipment<br/><a href="http://www.gardnermarsh.com" target="_blank">www.gardnermarsh.com&nbsp;&rarr;</a>',
sub_title: "679 North Michigan Ave. Chicago, IL 60611",
slides: gardner
}, {
lat: 35.885821,
long: -78.749571,
title: 'Dougherty Equipment Company<br/><a href="http://www.doughertyequipment.com" target="_blank">www.doughertyequipment.com&nbsp;&rarr;</a>',
sub_title: "679 North Michigan Ave. Chicago, IL 60611",
slides: dougherty
}, {
lat: 47.6632853,
long: -122.300746,
title: 'Apple Seattle Store',
sub_title: "2656 NE University Village Street Seattle, WA 98105",
slides: b
}, {
lat: 36.1276138,
long: -115.16803270000003,
title: 'Apple Las Vegas store',
sub_title: "3200 Las Vegas Blvd. Las Vegas, NV 89109"
}, {
lat: 30.258303,
long: -97.807986,
title: 'Apple Austin store',
sub_title: "2901 S. Capital of Texas Highway Austin, TX 78746",
slides: b
}]
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little hard to say exactly when not knowing you exact way of code-setup.

But if you keep a reference to the marker, infowindow (popup) and the off-map link then you can open the infowindow with that reference by

#### Html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="onLinkClick(1)">www.link.com</a>
```

#### Javascript

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});
var markerArray = [];
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
});
markerArray.push(marker);

function findMarker(markerPosition){
 return markerArray[markerPosition];
}


function onLinkClick(markerPosition){
    var marker = findMarker(markerPosition);
    infowindow.open(map,marker)
}
```

---

Edit: To low rep to comment.
if you have something similar to example at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Then i would push all the markers in an array for further use. And also ofcourse save reference to the infowindow.
And then you could very much reuse them as the code above.

---

Edit2: See changes above.
This is a crude way of doing it but should work well. Now you only have to find a way to actually get the right number/reference to each of the links som how

---

Edit 3: Aah you are using some library which is extending/wrapping the ordinary google.maps-api. Actually seems almost even more tricky to use properly rather than just using original googlemaps-api.
And honestly i dont know how that library works with reusing those kind of variables.
Are you only using the specialized map for styling the popups? If so I would definately trow that lib out and just go for the original maps-api. and work with customized "markers" and customzed "infowindow". No more than a little css and markup. Really good documentation on: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Yes, i'm wondering how the on map pop up are currently being called/referenced, and if I can use those same references off the map as well.

Comment: In your above example, how would the code for click link itself look? I'm a javascript newby, btw.

Comment: I've added the Javascript code from my example to my original post if that helps. The makers are placed on the map based on the long: and lat: values that I enter.

Comment: I'm using it because it is easy for my client to update and add additional information and company logos to. So unfortunately I need to keep using it, if only we could figure out how to get the right numbers/references.

Comment: Nils, I noticed in my example page when you hover over the green map icons, you'll see a number in the link description field. They are 0,1,2,3,4, etc. I wonder if these could be used to open them up?

Comment: That might absolutely be possible, guess it depends one The API stylized-map is exposing.